# Is there any way to easily convert Ruby code to PHP?

Tags: php, ruby

We need to develop a functionality for one of our client's website. However, we actually have that code ready in Ruby. Is there any way to directly convert that ruby code to PHP?

Comment: Umm, no. How much code are you actually looking at? Someone familiar with both languages should be able to quickly copy the functionality in PHP.

Comment: I feel like I should send you a sympathy card. What a sad thing to have to do...

Comment: I can't post an answer here, but I have [written a translator](https://github.com/jarble/transpiler) that converts a subset of Ruby into PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say Ruby code, what exactly are you talking about? A snippet of code that needs to be used somewhere on the website? Or perhaps an entire Ruby on Rails application?

In either case you're not going to find an automated solution to convert this to PHP. In the first case, a skilled PHP developer (ideally with at least some Ruby knowledge) should be able to convert this to PHP fairly easily. But if you're talking about an entire website, it's obviously a much larger undertaking, as you're not just dealing with your own code but with the underlying web application stack. Perhaps you can convert this app to a PHP based MVC framework like CakePHP, but again, you'd need an experienced PHP developer to do this, and in this case I think this would be a difficult task if they aren't also fairly familiar with Ruby on Rails.