# Ruby on Rails to PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, codeigniter, heroku

I have no experience in Ruby on Rails.  I employed a developer to create a tour booking system for my site (php codeigniter).  He developed it using Ruby on Rails in heroku and then linked to it by iframe in my front end.

Problem is

1. MS explorer doesnt display it,
2. issues with dynamic booking form sizing,
3. Cookies for the cart doesnt work as it's cross site and in iOS sometimes the security denies the cookies so system doesnt work,
4. Site massively slowed down due to the http requests.

Is there a way to convert the ruby system into php so i can just have it on my local site?  Can anyone think of any other solution if not??

thanks

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611682/is-there-any-way-to-easily-convert-ruby-code-to-php

Comment: Converting to php/codeigniter would require a rewrite. For the IE and UI problems you could probably fix them with CSS.  You could resolve cross-site issues by hosting both apps through the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not easy way to convert a language to another, with some exception (like language that compiles to another one, for example CoffeeScript to JavaScript). Using iframes will create security problems, which in turn trigger (modern) browser to block them.

So, what are your options?

- Use the Ruby & Rails website as a subdomain of your main. Example, if your site runs on chambers.com and that the Ruby on Rails site is about invoicing, it could be on invoncing.chambers.com, and you could use links from one to the other
- Rewrite either the Ruby or the PHP part, depending on size & team capability

Comment: Thank you.  I decided to code each tour page in Ruby on a subdomain bookings.example.com and link from codeigniter on main domain to ruby on subdomain.  Now my challenge is the link between the two and routing!  wish me luck!